# How to check if an element string in a numpy array can be changed into an integer and if so, change it? python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

If i have a list or numpy array with strings in it, how to check if the elements are numeric and if so, change them into integers and replace them?

```
list1 = [["australia", "1", "5000, "red"], ["canada", "4", "412", "green"],...]
list1 = np.asarray(list1)

k = 0
for item in list1:
   j = 0
   for element in item:
      if element.isnumeric():
          list1[k][j] = int(element)
      j = j + 1
   k = k + 1
```

But it didn't work to give me output of:

```
[["australia" 1  5000 "red"], ["canada" 4 412 "green"],...]
```

Comment: Did you expect the output to be a numpy array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with 1 line:

```
list1 = [[int(x) if x.isnumeric() else x for x in lst] for lst in list1]
```

Comment: output for this gave me: [['a', 'u', 's', 't', 'r'', 'a', 'l', 'i', 'a'] , [1],  [5000], ['r', 'e', 'd']......

Comment: print(list1)
The output is: [['australia', 1, 5000, 'red'], ['canada', 4, 412, 'green']]

Comment: oh yes, sorry i must've printed something else... thanks a lot!!

Comment: Noticed that it will work with a list but not with a numpy array.

Comment: is there a way to make it work with numpy array

Answer (score 0):

I ran it on my machine, your code works.

```
list1 = [["australia", "1", "5000", "red"], ["canada", "4", "412", "green"]]
#list1 = np.asarray(list1)

k = 0
for item in list1:
   j = 0
   for element in item:
      if element.isnumeric():
          list1[k][j] = int(element)
      j = j + 1
   k = k + 1
  
print(list1)
```

and the output is

```
[['australia', 1, 5000, 'red'], ['canada', 4, 412, 'green']]
```